# Usage of different ports by one email app

Tags: http, email, networking, tcp

I am learning about TCP, HTTP, and ports, I am confused about how they are used. Say, I want to create a mobile app for sending and receiving emails. I know that e.g. port 80 is used for HTTP traffic, and port 25 for email, and port 22 for login.

1. Will the mobile app use port 22 every time the user logs in in the app?
2. If an email has a picture, will this picture be loaded via port 80 as HTTP traffic?
3. For the actual email data, will the app use port 25?

Another thing that really confuses me: I've heard that only a single program can listen to a port. Now, **if a mobile phone has several email apps running, how do they manage to work at the same time?** If they both need to listen to ports 80, 22, 25 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not one question, but let me see if I can shed some light about the things that confuse you.

> I know that e.g. port 80 is used for HTTP traffic, and port 25 for
> email, and port 22 for login

Correct, to the most part. For example 443 is the HTTPS port. In any way, there is nothing stopping you on running your web server on port 8000 or if you really want to be nasty at 22 either. These are the recommended ports for each app and they are generally what is used. The reason for that is that when a client needs to make a connection to an app, they need both the IP and the port number of the app they want to connect. So it is common for web browsers to try and connect on 80 or 443. But you can always connect to a different port as well. I.e., if you go to http://some_url:8080 you will be making a connection to port 8080, instead of 80. Information such as port numbers is managed by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA). Take a look [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) for more information on port numbers and their uses.

> Will the mobile app use port 22 every time the user logs in in the app

Port 22 is (again generally) used by the secure shell application (SSH). This is NOT the same as when you enter your credentials in a website for example. All that happens using HTTP(S).

> If an email has a picture, will this picture be loaded via port 80 as
> HTTP traffic?

If an email is sent, it will go to the email server (likely running on port 25). All of the email transfer will happen using the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP), which will handle everything in the email payload and the encryption (if any) around the mail. I suggest looking at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) article and following the links from there if you are interested in SMTP.

> For the actual email data, will the app use port 25?

I believe this is covered by my previous answer.

Regarding your final question. You are correct a single app can only listen to one port. But the "app" in this case would be the server. So to give you an example, let's say that an email server is hosted on machine with IP 1.2.3.4 and runs on port 25.

Now, if you have multiple email **clients**, they will all connect to that IP:port server tuple. However, the clients will open connections from your mobile phone's IP (let's say 5.6.7.8) to that server. But each connection will be using a different **local port**, and this is how multiple connections can be established at the same time to the same destination. The same scenario happens when you open two tabs and access the same website. You connect to the same IP:port tuple of the server, but do it from different ports on your machine.

To understand this, you need to understand that applications over the Internet use IP:port 4-tuples to identify a connection. The 4-tuple contains `(Server_IP, Server_Port, Client_IP, Client_Port)`. If any one things in this 4-tuple is different the connection that it identifies is also different.